# Скругление двух углов у кнопки на 100%

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать такое скругление?

```
border-radius: 0 100%;
```

не то.

Answer (score 1):

Воть, span просто создал, чтобы проверить, как внутренние элементы будут влиять на радиусы. Вроде рабочая штука получилась.

```css
.skruglenie {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 0 15vw 0 15vw;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
span {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="skruglenie"><span></span></div>
```

Comment: Можете сокращать до `border-radius: 0 var(--bs-border-radius);`, это записать, равносильна этой записи: `border-radius: 0 var(--bs-border-radius) 0 var(--bs-border-radius);`.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Ну тут кто как хочет, так и пишет. Можно писать сокращённо, а можно полностью. Как я привык писать, так и пишу - это не является ошибкой

Comment: Конечно это не является ошибкой, вы абсолютно правы, я просто отметил, факт того, что вашу пропорцию можно сократить.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn {
        border-radius: 0 30px 0 30px;
    }
```

```html
<button class="btn">button</button>
```

Comment: я забыл сказать, что нельзя привязываться к высоте, поскольку, она может быть разная

Comment: Тогда используйте проценты или vw и vh

Answer (score 0):

Зачем что-то мудрить, есть 100% решение на любой размер элемента :)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cool-border-radius {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 0 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cool-border-radius"></div>
```

P.S. Хотя стоит отметить, что могут возникнуть проблемы, если высота и ширина будет слишком не прапрорциональны.

Comment: Вот именно, не пропорциональны, а значит процент задавать бессмысленно. Поэтому я вывел через переменные, задаёшь любой размер переменной и он автоматом будет подстраиваться под размер

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи да, пожалуй вы правы, думаю ваш способ более правильный в этом случае.